# Is it haram to use unused power of a computer without permission?

Tags: halal-haram, technology

Assalamualaikum, I am a hacker, but I do not want to use any of my skills to do anything that is haram. I would like to know if it is haram to use use the *remaining* **unused** power of a person's computer(*without his permission*) to help do some calculations? Note that this person is barely going to lose anything and half of any profit that I get from this will already go to charity. Should I do this or abandon the whole idea?

Comment: Would you consider it halal to open a locked door and enter the house of a stranger without his permission, in order to just measure the temperature of his house and then leave directly?

Comment: Well... I don't really know. I didn't do any harm to that stranger, and the temperature value was used for good. I mean, if someone did that to me, used the temperature value to get some money and gave half of that money to charity, I don't think I would mind.

Comment: check verse 24:27-28

Comment: I think that is an answer. Thank you, brothers.